# I can not get <cite> text to align right when formatting an HTML document

Tags: html, css

[Example of my code using the text align syntax.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXMGl.jpg)

```
<cite style="color: blue; font-style: normal; text-align: right">

Paul M. Barrett, The New York Times Book Review

</cite>
```

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes as links to images of code requires more effort to reproduce, and is considered poor formatting.

To improve your question, can you please post it as code?

Comment: Sure. I initially tried that but didn't get very far. I'm new here. Let me make a few changes

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block;` to your inline styles to correct this.

Code:

```
<cite style="color: blue; font-style: normal; text-align: right; display: block;">

Paul M. Barrett, The New York Times Book Review

</cite>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/ZwwQbq

Answer (score -1):

```css
cite {
    color: blue;
    line-height: 0.75rem;
}

.cite {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p class="cite"><cite>Paul M. Barrett, The New York Times Book Review</cite></p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).